Getting '404 Not Found' when triggering GitLab pipeline using curl POST request
I want to trigger a GitLab pipeline using a curl request with Bash. I'm following this GitLab documentation page: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#use-curl
Here's my curl request:
curl -X "POST" --form token="[valid GitLab access token]" --form ref="main" "https://[GitLab instance url]/api/v4/projects/37/trigger/pipeline"
I run the code and get {"message":"404 Not Found"} back as a response.
I verified the project id and access token by doing a GET request with the same values and it worked.
For reference this GET request worked:
curl -X "GET" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: [valid GitLab access token]" "https://[GitLab instance url]/api/v4/projects/37/pipelines/latest"
I've tried different combinations with the curl request syntax like using --request or putting the token and ref in the request string like this, ".../trigger/pipeline?token=[valid GitLab access token]&ref=main" but nothing works.
How do I get the curl POST request to work?

I figured out what was the issue. I was using the wrong token. Even though the group token I was using had full access to the GitLab API it didn't work. I had to go into the GitLab project I wanted to trigger the pipeline and generate a pipeline trigger token. It's under GitLab project -> Settings -> CI/CD -> Pipeline trigger token. Even though the GitLab documentation says you can use a CI/CD group token, it didn't work. The 404 Not Found error message is misleading.
